# Unable to import cookies from a csv file into a Requests Cookie Jar in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am new to Python (Python 3.8.3) and I want to perform the following task:

After fetching cookies from a Selenium session and storing them in a csv file, I subsequently want to import them into my Requests Cookie Jar.

This works flawlessly, if I import the cookie(s) manually by putting them in a list at the beginning of my script:

```
import requests
import csv

cookie_list = [

    [{'domain': 'en.wikipedia.org', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': […]}],
    [{'domain': 'en.wikipedia.org', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': […]}],
    [{'domain': 'en.wikipedia.org', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': […]}]

]

sm = requests.Session()

cookie_set = random.choice(cookie_list)
print(cookie_set)

jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
for cookie in cookie_set:
    jar.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], domain='en.wikipedia.org')
sm.cookies = jar
```

As soon as I try to import the cookies from a separate csv file, storing cookies from different sessions in separate rows, and try to set them in the Requests Cookie Jar, my script encounters an issue and gets the error code:

```
with open('testcookie.csv') as ck:
    csvReader = csv.reader(ck)
    cookies = list(csvReader)

sm = requests.Session()

cookie_set = cookies[1][0]
print(cookie_set)

jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
for cookie in cookie_set:
    jar.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], domain='en.wikipedia.org')
sm.cookies = jar
_________________________________________________________________

Traceback (most recent call last):
jar.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], domain='en.wikipedia.org')
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am pretty confused because the rows are absolutely the same no matter if I print out `(print(cookie_set))` a row from the manual created list or from the csv file after reading all rows into a list and index into that.

This is how my csv file looks like:[testcookie.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Azm.png)

What is the cause for this error code and how can I import the cookies from my csv file, that stores cookies from different sessions in each row?

I appreciate your help! Thanks in advance

Comment: The image you shared doesn't look like a CSV file at all, what are the actual contents of the file? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: The content in each row is basically the output from another script, that stores the cookies with the help of Selenium Webdriver command driver.get_cookies().

Comment: _The content in each row is basically the output from another script, that stores the cookies with the help of Selenium Webdriver command driver.get_cookies()._ That output doesn't really look like CSV to me. Can you share (part of) the file as text?